# Managed-CachingOptimized policy doesn't have any effect on caching

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

AWS Cloudfront default Managed-CachingOptimized policy doesn't have any effect on caching. The Cache TTL is still not separate for the images which are being served via AWS S3. Do we need to set caching headers or should we use a custom policy?

Cache TTL still shows up as None for all image extensions which gets mapped to this Origin